# 404 error in Node.js when doing app.get with postgres as Db

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I am learning Node.js through a tutorial to build a simple API.
I have my own postgres db and I am trying to retrieve a table and not use the sample db/dummy db in the tutorial. I am following everything in the tutorial, only thing is I am using my own db and getting 404 not found error.

My Index.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var db = require('../queries');

router.get('/api/preference', function(req,res){ res.send('hi'); })


module.exports = router;
```

Queries.js

```js
var promise = require('bluebird');

var options ={
    //Initialization options
    promiseLib : promise
};

var pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);
var db = pgp({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    database: 'pmc',
    user: 'tarun',
    password: 'pes'
});
var connectionstring = 'postgres://tarun:pes@localhost:5432/pmc';
var db = pgp(connectionstring);


//add query funtions

module.exports = {
    getAllPreference : getAllPreference
};


function getAllPreference(req,res,next){
    db.any('select * from core.preferences')
      .then(function(data){
        res.status(200)
           .json({
               status : 'success',
               data : data,
               message: 'Retrieved ALL preferences'
           });
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        return next(err);
      });
}
```

app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();



// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Error

Error: Not Found
    at D:\node-postgress-promises\app.js:32:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\node-postgress-promises\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\node-postgress-promises\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\node-postgress-promises\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\node-postgress-promises\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\node-postgress-promises\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at D:\node-postgress-promises\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
    at next (D:\node-postgress-promises\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (D:\node-postgress-promises\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (D:\node-postgress-promises\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

> Blockquote

Comment: You should `console.log` the `err` before returning like `.catch(function (err) {
console.log(err);
        return next(err);
      });`.

This will tell you what the error actually is. Surely it's not 404.

Comment: The database part got nothing to do with HTTP error 404.

Comment: @vitaly-t any inputs sire?

Comment: @OLDMONK that was the input. Focus on your HTTP service part, forget the database part, as it is unrelated here. Something in your HTTP service is wrong.

Comment: @vitaly-t something wrong with the route sir?i am new to this sir..so kinda looking for expert like you share some insights

Comment: My expertise is with the database side of things (being the author of pg-promise), you need an HTTP expert, which I'm not, sorry.

Comment: @vitaly-t Thank you for your time sir.i am glad the author of pg-promise library had time to go through my post.Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 0):

Change this portion of code as follow

```
exports.getAllPreference = function(req,res,next){
    console.log('h');
    db.any('select * from core.preferences')
      .then(function(data){
        res.status(200)
           .json({
               status : 'success',
               data : data,
               message: 'Retrieved ALL preferences'
           });
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        next(err);
      });
}
```

Remove below code in this file

```
module.exports = {
            getAllPreference= getAllPreference
}
```

Change your index.js file Remove below lines

```
module.exports = {
getAllPreference: getAllPreference
};

function getAllPreference(req, res, next) {};
```

And uncomment

```
module.exports = router;
```

Add below code for testing purpose. in index.js file

```
router.get('/api/preference', function(req,res){
     res.send('hi');

};
```

Comment: give your last trial at this. Also please say about the console.log written in getAllPreference.

Comment: you are not able to reach, getAllPreference function.

Comment: i think thats the case sir..i am used to to asp.net webapi..trying my hand in node for the first time..i am so confused now..is there prob with my route?

Comment: so http://localhost:3000/ returns Welcome to Express but http://localhost:3000/api/preference returns nothing

Comment: let do something for checking issue.

Comment: router.get('/api/preference', function(req,res){
     res.send('hi');

};

Comment: no response sir..i did changed the route to 
router.get('/api/preference', function(req,res){ res.send('hi'); })
when i check it with http postman tool..it gives this response Unexpected '<'

Comment: can you please test it by directly browser hit.

Comment: no response sir..i have edited my question with the detailed error.

Comment: did you change your index.js file?  properly exported "router" object in index.js file.

Comment: did you chaged your queries.js file. As I said in answer.

Comment: yes sir..i have edited my index in the question..you can check it

Comment: i have been following this tutorial-http://mherman.org/blog/2016/03/13/designing-a-restful-api-with-node-and-postgres/#.WOacU2l95XR...only thing is i am using my own db

Comment: are you restarting your server or not after making changes in code.

Comment: Server means node application.

Comment: after every change i am restarting the server sir

Comment: Please do one thing... Install nodemon  using this command "npm install nodemon -g" then stop your node server. Again start your server using this command "nodemon npm start"

Comment: Hey Lets meet tomorrow on skype at 9:00 IST , my id is sunil.eternal i will check your code and also can guide you about node.

Comment: Don't worry I will not charge for it.

Comment: sure sir.thanks..this is killing me now.thanks for your time.:)